Trying to Import a .whl as a library
Using Jupyter notebook in vscode and have gastronomy.whl in the same folder as the source code. Tried pip install gastronomy.whl and it doesn't work. Don't understand how I can make it so that I can just do import gastronomy as gas

As you can see, I tried the pip install command. I also tried sudo install to no avail. I even tried installing with the direct file address

What happened when you ran it the first time? What does %pip list show in regards to that package? Did you restart the kernel? Did you refresh your browser? Did you then try restarting Jupyter and your browser and your entire machine? You'd be better off using %pip install .... in the future in modern Jupyter everywhere. And don't use screenshots. And please make your title specific. You don't know if you could install a wheel and then import the corresponding package. You know this one isn't working. Please read How do I ask a good question?...

 Paying special attention to the sections on how to write a good title, heading 'Write a title that summarizes the specific problem', and the section 'Help others reproduce the problem' where it says to share what you know about the code, such as source etc. and to not use screenshots. A good way to think about a title is to imagine you were searching for the solution to your issue and had a large list of titles. Which one would look most pertinent to you right now?
